# Open-sourced pairwise learning models

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am solving a classification problem using pairwise-learning training set.
We have 2 classes: *bad* and *good*.
We also have pairs of objects $(a_i,b_i)_{i=1}^n$, meaning that object $a_i$ *is better* than $b_i$.
Each object is described through its real coordinates: $a_i = x_i^1, x_i^2, \dots x_i^k$.
My aim is to build such an algorithm, that says for test object which is bad and which is good.

The question is what open-sourced algorithms/programs/packages can you suggest for solving that kind of *pairwise-learning* problem.
I have found only svm-rank algorithm from [svm-light](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/index.html) project that handles such pairwise training data.
I wonder, didn't find anything similar in matlab/R/rapidminer.

Answer (score 3):

The R implementation of [sofia-ml](https://code.google.com/p/sofia-ml/), [RSofia](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSofia/RSofia.pdf) provides a couple of options, rank and query-norm-rank, that allow for pairwise learning. It's a fast SVM implementation out of Google. It's more barebones than some other R packages, but once you get it up and running I've found that it is a nice SVM option.